# Loading multiple modules with SymLoadModuleExW

Tags: debugging, winapi, symbols, dbghelp

I'm trying to load several symbol modules using the following code:

```
DWORD64 dwBaseDllSymLocal = 0;
SymInitializeW(GetCurrentProcess(), NULL, FALSE);
SymSetOptions(SYMOPT_DEBUG);

dwBaseDllSymLocal = SymLoadModuleExW(GetCurrentProcess(), NULL, L"C:\\module1.dll", NULL, 0, 0, NULL, 0);
if (0 == dwBaseDllSymLocal)
{
    __debugbreak();
}
```

*dwBaseDllSymLocal is 10000000 now.*

```
dwBaseDllSymLocal = SymLoadModuleExW(GetCurrentProcess(), NULL, L"C:\\module2.dll", NULL, 0, 0, NULL, 0);
if (0 == dwBaseDllSymLocal)
{
    __debugbreak();
}
```

*Dbghelp gives the following message:* `module1 is already loaded at 10000000`.

Same behavior happens when I try to load the same module twice. (unlike what is written in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681353(v=vs.85).aspx) of the function).

Last error is `ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS` though it doesn't seem relevant, because last error has this value following the first successful function call too.

Is it possible to load several modules with `SymLoadModuleExW`? What is the right way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You are loading these binaries outside of the context of a debugger session, right? In which case, the fifth parameter, `BaseOfDll`, might be causing a problem:

> The load address of the module. If the value is zero, the library obtains the load address from the symbol file.

When loading a binary standalone, it might just use 10000000 for everything... in which case, the second module load would conflict with the first one. So try passing something different there.

> Last error is [...] though it doesn't seem relevant, because last error has this value following the first successful function call too.

If the function succeeds, the last error is not applicable; it could contain anything, but you should ignore it unless the documentation explicitly says that it sets the last error in success cases.

Comment: Are there any guidelines for the `BaseOfDll`? How can I know which values to give it?